# How can I correctly make the fetch api call in react?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api

I wanted to fetch the result from the dummy API with react js using fetch. But I'm getting the error of "SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0" from console.log()

```
handleSubmit(event) {

fetch({
  url:'http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees',
  mode: 'cors',
  method: 'GET',
  dataType: 'json',
  headers: {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*',
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
  }
})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {
    console.log(data);

})
.catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
});

event.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: Seems okay! can you provide a little bit more description about the error log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fetch's first argument is 'url' and second argument is 'options'.Try out this one:

```
handleSubmit(event) {
    fetch('http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees', {
      mode: 'cors',
      method: 'GET',
      dataType: 'json',
      headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*',
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
      }
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data);

    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
    });
    event.preventDefault();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are getting 404 response which is giving error while converting to json.
I have printed response before converting to json in below code. Check your console after running code.

```
fetch({
  url:'http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees',
  mode: 'cors',
  method: 'GET',
  dataType: 'json',
  headers: {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*',
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
  }
})
.then(response => {
    console.log(response);
  response.json()})
.then(data => {
    console.log(data);

})
.catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually get this error when I have a problem on the backend. Check if on the backend your API is returning the data in a json format.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated one

```
fetch('http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees')
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(data) {
    console.log("result",data);
  });
```

The Promise returned from **fetch()** won’t reject on **HTTP error status** even if the response is an **HTTP 404 or 500**. Instead, it will resolve normally (with ok status set to false), and it will only reject on network failure or if anything prevented the request from completing.

I would prefer to use with **Axios** as its best recommended and suited for react applications.

```
axios.get( 'http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees')
            .then( response => {
              console.log("result",response.data)
            } )
            .catch( error => {
                 console.log("error",error)
            } );
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you make a request to the server and parse the response as JSON, but it’s not JSON.

```
fetch('http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees').then(res => res.json())
```

The actual request worked fine. It got a response. But the res.json() is what failed.

[Read this for more suggestion](https://daveceddia.com/unexpected-token-in-json-at-position-0/)